# How to inherit constructor from a non-direct base class?

Tags: c++

How can I inherit a constructor from Grandpa(*Non-Direct Base*) to Son? For example:

```
class Grandpa
{
public:
  Grandpa();
  ~Grandpa();
};

class Dad : public Grandpa
{
public:
  Dad();
  ~Dad();
};

class Son : public Dad
{
public:
  using Grandpa::Grandpa;
  ~Son();
};
```

> ERROR: "can only inherit constructor from direct base"

There is a way how to make it work?

Comment: "There is a way how to make it work?" - no, there isn't. And what would it mean if there was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to inherit a non-direct base class' constructor. However, you can still use it. If you want to pass a value to **Grandpa**'s constructor from **Son**'s constructor, you can do something like this;

```
class Grandpa
{
public:
  Grandpa(string surname){
  // some codes in the constructor
  }
  ~Grandpa();
};

class Dad : public Grandpa
{
public:
  Dad(string surname) : Grandpa(surname){};
  ~Dad();
};

class Son : public Dad
{
public:
  Son(string surname) : Dad(surname){};
  ~Son();
};
```

Here what we do is simply, passing the value from **Son's** constructor to **Dad's** constructor, and it is just propagating to the **Grandpa**'s constructor.

Answer (score -1):

The relation of *non virtual* inheritance is just as direct and strong as membership: a class constructor absolutely controls the invocation of the constructors of its members *and* the invocation of the constructors of its direct *non virtual* bases. When a class is written, the way its members and direct *non virtual* bases is specified in the source code; changing that could invalidate a fundamental invariant of the class.

Using a non virtual base constructor directly from a further derived class would break the C++ model.